# $('input') is returning empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Odd problem, tested this on chrome and mozilla and it worked somehow in safari $('input') is returning empty.?? Am i doing something wrong here? My code is below

Javascript:

```
function prepare_publisher_profile_input_fields(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type === 'submit') {
            inputs[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }

    var element = this;

    $('input').click(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
        $('input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#publisher_profile_save").removeAttr('disabled');
        $("#publisher_profile_save").bind('click', function () {
            publisher_profile_save();
        });

        $("#publisher_profile_cancel").removeAttr('disabled');

        $("#publisher_profile_cancel").bind('click', function () {
            publisher_profile_cancel();
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="company_name" value="" class="input-xlarge form-required" readonly="readonly" id="company_name">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" class="input-xlarge form-required" readonly="readonly" id="username">
<a href="#" id="publisher_profile_save" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" disabled="disabled">Save</a>
<a href="#" id="publisher_profile_cancel" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" disabled="disabled">Cancel</a>
```

Help please.

Comment: Calling `$()` **always** returns a jQuery object. What do you mean by it is returning "empty"? What is happening and what do you expect to happen? What are you trying to do? What exactly is the problem? You just said something does not work, but we don't even know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Why are you mixing DOM manipulation functions with jQuery?

Comment: If your going to use jQuery, you should stick to using jQuery, the whole point is that it means you don't have to do `document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");` because instead you can do `$('input')`

Comment: @FelixKling: All that doesn't really matter as the issue here is embarrassingly clear.

Comment: @Purmou: Then please tell me what the issue is?

Comment: @FelixKling: He's selecting `input` elements instead of `a` elements.

Comment: +1 @Purmou. this one is so full of facepalm...

Comment: @Purmou: Maybe, maybe not... I'm sure there is more HTML. And why would he bind new event handlers inside the event handler to the same elements? The whole sentence *"tested this on chrome and mozilla and it worked somehow in safari $('input') is returning empty"* does not make a lot of sense. "worked somehow" where? Chrome? Mozilla? Safari? What does worked somehow mean? If what you say is true, how could it have "worked somehow"? You reached a conclusion based on the information given and I say there is not enough information in order to help.

Comment: Please explain what is happening and what you expect to happen. A http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be very helpful too.

Comment: @FelixKling Then why did the OP even bother posting that chunk of HTML? If he's not trying to select it, and there are no event handlers attached (that we can see) that call the function in question, what was the point? -- EDIT: OP added input fields... EDIT2: added "that call the function in question"

Comment: @MicronXD: He working with those elements: `$("#publisher_profile_save").bind('click', ...`, refers to one of the links. As I already said, it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: +1 @FelixKling re: jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

Those are anchor tags, not input tags. Change the `$("input")` selector to `$("a")`.

Comment: edited my question, I used $('input') for those input type tags.

Comment: OK. that makes more sense :P  --  Please post a jsfiddle as @FelixKling suggested.